# C# search in JSON array data

Tags: c#, json, geojson

My first method converting input data returns JSON and its type is string. Return string looks like:

```
[{
    "coordinates": [102.5, 24.123],
    "type": "Point",
    "properties": {
        "tsu": "",
        "name": "china: yunnan province; vietnam: hanoi",   
        "yyyymmdd": "19700104"
    }
}, {
    "coordinates": [-73.7955, -51.943],
    "type": "Point",
    "properties": {
        "tsu": "tsu",
        "name": "s. chile",
        "yyyymmdd": "19700614"
    }
}, {
    "coordinates": [28.745, 39.18],
    "type": "Point",
    "properties": {
        "tsu": "",
        "name": "turkey: demirci, manisa",
        "yyyymmdd": "19700423"
    }
}]
```

How to access data stored in this kind of string?

Comment: It looks like JSON, you tagged it JSON, so perhaps you should use a JSON library like json.net

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Please don't use "thanks in advantage", "thanks in advice" or "thanks in advance" on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 0: Fix the typo in your JSON string (I edited your post to do that for you).

Step 1: Go to [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/), put in your JSON, and let it generate the classes for you.

Step 2: Install Json.Net from NuGet.

Step 3: Write `var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(myJsonString);`

Step 4: Use the object like you would any other object in C#.

Comment: or you can dersialize to dynamic

Comment: @pm100, very true. I tend to prefer deserializing into strongly-typed classes as it provides intellisense and compile-time checking, but YMMV.

Comment: sometimes each json object has different schema , in that case you need dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Use Json.Net.     Very easy to Serialize and deserialize any .NET object.

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: Yep. Also available as a NuGet package.